# Android GridView : clean code for asynch loading of remote images (with ViewHolder and AsynchTask)

Tags: java, android, listview, gridview, android-asynctask

I am looking for a clean and simple code for asynch loading of remote images (located on a server) in a GridView (which seems to mean using ViewHolder and AsynchTask). I am not satisfied by what I found up to now (use of AsynchTask without ViewHolder, use of ViewHolder without AsynchTask, etc...and each time something is not clean in the code given)

Anybody can give some code or link to a (clean) sample project ?

Thanks !

Comment: where are the remote images? server? external sd?

Answer (score 0):

If the images are on some server, and you know all the full path's to them
consider using volley, it manages all the downloading & caching in background.

simple example can be found [here](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2014/02/01/android-volley-tutorial/)

Minimum code, minimum effort :)

Comment: Indeed, you can use volley or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) (created by folks at Square) which is probably simpler to use only for pictures.

Comment: I would suggest volley, even if picasa or the nostras are great, but if you develop on google platforms already, use google implementation for that :)

Comment: Volley is great because it's one library you can use for both your classic HTTP requests and image download into scrollable view. However, its lack of documentation makes it really hard to use. That's why I massively use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) (along with [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) for cache) and [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) within my app.